# Google ANGLE(Almost Native Graphics Layer Engine) translation support

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

Almost Native Graphics Layer Engine (ANGLE) is a translation tool to support WebGL in Windows Chrome.

In Google's ANGLE Doc, I Notice the following statement in https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle:

> ANGLE currently provides translation from OpenGL ES 2.0, 3.0 and 3.1 to Vulkan, desktop OpenGL, **OpenGL ES**, Direct3D 9, and Direct3D 11

It makes me confused that why ANGLE need to translate OpenGL ES to GL ES?

Is that the same thing?

Comment: My guess is the point of supporting OpenGL ES in ANGLE is that you make an app that uses ANGLE and not care what platform you're on. Further if you're lucky, ANGLE might work around bugs in your OpenGL ES driver.

Comment: Yes, GL ES is just another way to say OpenGL ES. @gman's comment is probably right.